# Heroku pg:backups:restore from public_url. Backup not found.

Tags: postgresql, heroku, amazon-s3

I am trying to copy my local Postgres database to Heroku.
So I use **pg:backups:restore** from a publicly accessible URL.

As mentioned in the documentation, I have downloaded my Postgres dump to Amazon S3 and gave the public access. The link to file is: https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/kirillch/localizedb.sql.

So now I run a command:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore 'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/kirillch/localizedb.sql' DATABASE_URL -a my_app_name
```

and get an error:

> Backup `https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/kirillch/localizedb.sql`
>   not found for *my_app*

What could be done to fix the issue?

Answer (score 6):

For windows users;

`heroku pg:backups:restore "https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump" DATABASE_URL`

According to the official docs, be sure to use double-quotes around the remote url if you're using windows. [see official docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import)